# Input just from a single partition to stream anaytics

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to make a stream analytics job take in input from just one partition?

I have six different jobs attached to same eventhub and each of them uses a subset of the messages coming in based on one of the input columns. Is it possible to force the jobs read just their subset as input and not the others by maybe using the partitionkey in event hub messages and partition by clause in stream analytics?

Right now all jobs are reading all the data (as it designed to be) and this is probably increasing the network costs and SU units.

Comment: Hi, One solution may be to add a filter on the PartitionID in Azure Stream Analytics. However that will still require ASA to access all partitions but may be a little more optimized than filtering on the value of the columns.

Comment: It sounds like you need a Topic instead...